# Is there a way to store a JS function in with Prisma in PostgreSQL?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, next.js, prisma

I have a data model like follows:

```
export class Ability {
    readonly id: string;
    readonly name: string;
    readonly description: string;
    trigger = (event: any): boolean => { return false; };       // on each event execute this function to check wheteher the ability is triggered
    effect = (event: any) => { };                               // if the ability is triggered apply the effect and return a new event

    constructor({ id, name, description, trigger, effect }: any) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.trigger = trigger;
        this.effect = effect;
    }

}
```

I was wondering whether it is possible to store the trigger and effect function of my Ability model in PostgreSQL using Prisma, so far my approach is to query the Ability via Prisma and map the id with the corresponding trigger and effect, but I would like to avoid doing this if possible.

Comment: Relational databases like PostgreSQL are designed to store structured data, not executable code or functions in the format of JavaScript/TypeScript functions. While it's technically possible to store JavaScript/TypeScript functions in a database, the typical approach is to store references to these functions or their string representations, and handle the mapping or execution in the application logic. This approach provides a balance between flexibility, maintainability, and security.